# PHP show MySQL Table in HTML

Tags: php, mysql

i am using this code to display a full MySQL Table:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM billing ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($rs);
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($rs);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

this is showing every column heading but only 2 columns data

how can i make it show all columns without having to list each column name/array number?

Comment: if you know how many rows will be returned, you just put echo <td> in a while => while (index< numberOfRows) {echo "<td>$row[index]</td>"; index++;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate though all columns in each row.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM billing ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($rs);
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($rs);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $index => $data) {
       echo "<td>".$data."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: perfect - thanks. if i added links to the column headings, how could i do it so it would be <a href="page.php?orderby=COL_HEADING&order=ASC"><td>{$field->name}</td></a> and then if that is the current page make it change to order=DESC

Comment: Use GET for the querystring parameters and then concatenate the SQL query with ORDER BY and ASC/DESC. Just string manipulation.

Comment: dont suppose you have an example please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45732/discussion-between-cardeol-and-user2710234)

Answer (score 3):

Use `mysql_fetch_array($rs)` instead of mysql_fetch_row($rs) and access each row of the resultset `$rs` by using the field names called above which will simplifies your query..
Try so..

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
        echo "<td>{$row[$i]}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM billing ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($rs);
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++) {
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($rs);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $numrows){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what? it will still pull the most recent $i when it gets to the second loop.

Comment: il you have 3 rows with 4 fields, $i will go up to 12, so it will crash when trying to access $row[5];

Comment: for futur reader : iamde_coder have moved the $i=0 in the first loop